# Html file won't update when i save and refresh

Tags: html

I've written a code for some reason it won't refresh. I've tried a lot of things, comparing it with an example html page from w3 schools (that one does update when something is changed), tried to clear cache and use different browsers. Currently i am not using a server but just doing the front end first.

Here is the code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang = "en">

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">

<title>Vjeran Bach</title>
</head>


<body>

<div class = "content">
<h1>Vjeran Bach Services</h1>
<p>Web and graphic design</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Edit: The problem is that atom is not saving anything.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work.

Comment: try opening it on Incognito tab (Ctrl+Shift+N in chrome) and check if you see any difference

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have saved the updates to the file? If it is not saved, the browser will only serve the previously saved version of the file.

Another thing you could try (provided it is a .html file): find the file in your file system (Finder/My Computer) and drag it to your browser window, then you should see the updated version.

Comment: Thanks! I opened the file in notepad (I am using Atom) and now i see that the file isn't actually changed, any idea how I can make Atom save it? Whenever i click save or use ctrl + s it doesn't actually change anything but in the application itself it shows that it is saved when in reality it is not.

Comment: I don't use Atom myself, but I would suggest VS Code. If you open the file in notepad, and try save it as yourfilename.html and serve that, does it work? At least that allows you to isolate the problem to the Atom software.

In regards to the spaces, yes, not invalid, my apologies.